# PHP Mail - Send only when there is a POST

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, email

I am building a simple mobile application whereby the users have a form to fill in which will then be sent to my email address.  I am using `JSON` and then a `PHP` to forward the `POST` details to my email.

My only issue is this, when you access the file on my host, say `www.example.com/forward.php` , I am receiving empty emails in my mailbox.

Is there a way to only send the email when there is a `POST`?  Is there something that I can do to make it more secure?  I have no idea when it comes to PHP and I just used a snippet from the PHP manual ([Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```
<?php

if(isSet($_POST['submit']))
{
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['password'];
 $password = $_POST['email'];

if($name !="" && $email !="" && $password !="")
{
  // Send mail ; 
}
else
{
 echo "All fields are mandatory";

}

}
else
{
 //echo "You can not access this URL directly"; 
 header('location:http://www.example.com');
}

?>
```

Comment: is it possible to list multiple values that are required?  such as below?

if(isSet($_POST['name', 'surname', 'email']))

Comment: also in the else part, is it possible to redirect the user to the main site, say www.example.com rather than displaying a message?

Answer (score 2):

```
//If this page has no POST data, then don't go any further
if (!$_POST) {
//Die with a "bad request" header
http_response_code(400);
die();
}
```

It's worth adding that this kind of script gets abused by spam bots all the time, especially by replaying POST data. You might want to consider some additional security if this is being deployed. For starters, other than just checking for POST data - you should check each field you require is there and in a valid form.

Comment: let's say I have a name, surname, email and date.  How would I be able to know whether they are in valid form in PHP?  I am doing some validation JS wise, but how can this be checked in PHP then?

Comment: There are multiple ways, but filter_var jumps to mind. http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if (isset($_POST["some value that should be posted"]))` for this.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $message = 'Message from your website:' . $_POST['message'];
        mail('to@example.com', 'Subject', $message);
        echo 'Thanks for your message!';
    } else {
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- your form fields here -->
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can be nicely achieved by checking that the $_POST variable is/are set. So if someone tries to access the file from any other method it will give them a message or redirect them.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['surname']) AND  isset($_POST['email'])){
    // Send your email ; 
}

else{
    //redirect
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
}
```